# grpc-java: setting enableRetry and maxRetryAttempt is not Retrying

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Grpc client is not retrying and failed with UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Currently I am setting the retry and maxRetryAttempt like below:

```
Channel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(address.getTarget(), address.getPort())
            .enableRetry()
            .maxRetryAttempts(3)
            .intercept(interceptors)
            .sslContext(context.build())
            .build();
```

Is enableRetry and maxRetryAttempt supported in io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.18.0?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java#L135

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither `enableRetry()` nor `maxRetryAttempts()` configures retry on a per-method basis. `enableRetry()` enabled the entire "subsystem," such that configuration will be followed; eventually it will be enabled by default, bu that wouldn't imply retries would happen for all methods. And `maxRetryAttempts()` *limits* the configuration; if the configuration says to do 5 and you set the limit to 3, then only 3 will be done. But it doesn't increase the number of retry attempts.

The "configuration" that I keep referring to comes from service config. See [gRFC A6 Client Retries](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A6-client-retries.md#integration-with-service-config) for the configuration keys. Service config itself is not currently enabled by default as well. For retries, the easiest way to try it out is to use `ManagedChannelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig(Map serviceConfig)` that was added to v1.20.0 (soon to be released). But you can also use TXT records in DNS and pass `-Dio.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolverProvider.enable_service_config=true` when executing your binary.

Retries and service config are currently both experimental.

Comment: Eric - I'm finding it very difficult to get good documentation on advanced gRPC configuration (particularly in Java). Loads of docs for getting started, but almost none on configuring things like retries, backoff, etc. Do I just have to keep search SO etc or are there docs on these things that I'm missing?

Comment: For service config, looking through https://github.com/grpc/proposal is probably the best. But service config via DNS is experimental, which is why there is the hidden `enable_service_config=true`. Retries are also experimental. The Javadoc for ManagedChannelBuilder generally has okay documentation. And you can watch the grpc-java release notes.

Comment: How to implement retry with io.grpc:grpc-core:1.24.0
These apis were implemented from 1.31.0

Comment: `enableRetry()` was in 1.11 and `defaultServiceConfig()` was in 1.20. That said, there have been multiple bug fixes since those releases. @vkrishna17, what APIs are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For enabling retries in a GRPC client, as mentioned by @Eric using `defaultServiceConfig` a way to provide default configuration for a ManagedChannel. This configuration can include settings like load balancing policies, method configuration (like timeouts, retry policies, etc.), and service parameters. You can set the `defaultServiceConfig` when building the ManagedChannel using the `defaultServiceConfig` method, which accepts a Map<String, ?> representing the service configuration in JSON format.

Here's an example of how you might define and set a defaultServiceConfig for a ManagedChannel in Kotlin:

```
private val grpcChannel: ManagedChannel  by lazy {
    OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(BuildConfig.API_GRPC_URL)
        .defaultServiceConfig(getServiceConfig())
        .useTransportSecurity()
        .build()
}

private fun getServiceConfig(): Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>>> {
    // Define the default service configuration
    val retryPolicy = mapOf(
        "maxAttempts" to "3",
        "initialBackoff" to "1s",
        "maxBackoff" to "5s",
        "backoffMultiplier" to 2.0,
        "retryableStatusCodes" to listOf("UNAVAILABLE", "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED")
    )

    val methodConfig = mapOf("retryPolicy" to retryPolicy)
    return mapOf("methodConfig" to listOf(methodConfig))
}
```

1. A retryPolicy is defined with parameters like maxAttempts, initialBackoff, maxBackoff, backoffMultiplier, and a list of retryableStatusCodes.
2. This retryPolicy is included in a methodConfig.
3. The methodConfig is part of the serviceConfig which is set on the ManagedChannel using defaultServiceConfig(serviceConfig).

This configuration specifies that the channel should retry calls for methods under certain conditions (like if the status code is UNAVAILABLE or RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED).